# How to format QRadioButton without label

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qradiobutton

Currently, the radiobutton widget is formatted this way:

[image]

I want to get rid of the text completely, and center the indicator inside it's widget. So that it looks like this:

[image]

What do I need to do to format the widget this way? I am using the editor, but certain chunks of my code are handwritten, so I would prefer that the answer work between both. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a QProxyStyle to move the position of the QRadioButton indicator:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def subElementRect(self, element, option, widget):
        r = super().subElementRect(element, option, widget)
        if element in (
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_RadioButtonIndicator,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_RadioButtonFocusRect,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_RadioButtonClickRect,
        ):
            r.moveCenter(option.rect.center())
        return r


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)

    for _ in range(3):
        btn = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: palette(button);")
        btn.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        lay.addWidget(btn)

    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

**Update:**

This change can not be observed in Qt Designer so you will have to use code, for example:

```
├── main.py
└── mainwindow.ui
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>130</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>221</width>
      <height>221</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(252, 233, 79);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py**

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def subElementRect(self, element, option, widget):
        r = super().subElementRect(element, option, widget)
        if element in (
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_RadioButtonIndicator,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_RadioButtonFocusRect,
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_RadioButtonClickRect,
        ):
            r.moveCenter(option.rect.center())
        return r


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())
    w = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "mainwindow.ui"))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

<sup>**Note:** I added a background color to the QRadioButton so that the position can be distinguished.</sup>

Comment: How would I implement this into the builder?

Comment: @Laif mmm, explain yourself better, a [MRE] would help me understand you

Comment: I'm referring to the QT Designer application. It lets you design UI pages through a GUI. I can't give you code as it literally doesn't use it.

Comment: @Laif Exactly, I need you to provide the .ui which is an XML so open the .ui with any text editor and copy the XML into your question

Comment: I haven’t written anything yet, do you want me to put the basic XML for a radio button?

Comment: @Laif Forget the moment of the above, first tell me how do you run the .ui?

Comment: I’ve not incorporated any .ui code yet, I just started using the designer.

Comment: @Laif Unfortunately it is necessary to have code so I added an example.